# SQL set a column to true if some conditions meet

Tags: sql, mariadb

Got 3 tables, said

mail

```
{
  id: number,
  content: string
}
```

player

```
{
  id: number,
  name: string
}
```

is_mail_read

```
{
  mail_id: number,
  player_id: number
}
```

What I want to achieve:

Given a player_id, return the mails with a column `is_read` which is true (or 1) if there is a record in `is_mail_read`, false if there isn't.

For example:

```
[
  {  
    id: 2,
    content: "I am a mail",
    is_read: true
  },
  {  
    id: 3,
    content: "I am a mail too",
    is_read: false
  },...
]
```

I have tried left join but got no idea what to do next.
The database is MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
select m.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from is_mail_read imr
                where imr.mail_id = m.id and
                      imr.player_id = ?  -- your desired player id
               )
       ) as read_flag
from mail m;
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally use `EXISTS` like you suggested. And just want to remind there should be `imr.player_id = ? AND imr.mail_id = m.id` in line 4.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with using LEFT JOIN. Now you simply check, if for the record in the `mail` table there is a record in the `player` table by checking if the joined record is NULL or not.

I'm assuming that you want to display all mails and return the info if a mail is read for a specific player. Then you have to filter for the player in the `JOIN` clause, not the `WHERE` clause. If you do it in the `WHERE` clause, you implicitly turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Except when you write the `WHERE` clause like

```
WHERE p.name = "John" OR p.name IS NULL
```

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT
m.id,
m.content,
IF(p.id IS NULL, false, true) AS is_read
FROM 
mail m
LEFT JOIN is_mail_read imr ON m.id = imr.mail_id
LEFT JOIN player p ON imr.player_id = p.id AND p.name = "John"
```

Comment: @Nick Yes, you can shorten it like that. I tend to keep it as readable and self explaining as possible when posting answers to users that don't have that much experience. If you knew how often I had to explain what a boolean expression is afterwards...